# How can I slice an object horizontally into equal pieces?

Tags: objects, workflow

My question is how can I split or slice up horizontally a 3D object into ten (or more) equal pieces, and every piece observe and rotate individually?
Thanx!

Answer (score 7):

### **Boolean modifiers**

I'll report the main passages of the method suggested by [BlendersSushi](http://blendersushi.blogspot.it/) in [this article](http://blendersushi.blogspot.it/2013/05/modifier-x-python-boolean-modifier-for.html).
[image]
Basically it uses the **Boolean modifier** in combination with **thin planes**.

---

Start from creating the **Array** of evenly spaced planes

[image]

Apply the Array modifier and add a **Solidify** modifier with the minumum thickness possible (we'll lose the part inside the extruded plane)

[image]

Apply the modifier and **Separate by Loose part** by enter in edit mode and press <kbd>P</kbd>.

[image]

**Select** all the plane and make the object to cut the Active object. Then **Run the script**:

```
import bpy

# Get all selected except Active Object
slave_objects = (bpy.context.selected_objects)

# Get Active Object
master_object = bpy.context.active_object

# Iterate each newly created Modifier to point to corresponding slave objects

for num, slave in enumerate(slave_objects[:-1]):
    print(slave.name)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = master_object
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')


    current_modifier_name = bpy.context.object.modifiers[num].name

    bpy.context.object.modifiers["{current_modifier_name}".format(current_modifier_name=current_modifier_name)].operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["{current_modifier_name}".format(current_modifier_name=current_modifier_name)].object = bpy.data.objects["{slave_name}".format(slave_name = slave.name)]
```

[image]

After a while, you'll have the object automatically filled with **Boolean modifiers.**

[image]

Apply them, then add an **Edge split** modifier to get rid of shanding artifacts

[image]

Run the **Origin to geometry** command for an easier object handling.

[image]

Now you are able to rotate/translate each object.

[image]

By pressing <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> you'll be able to get in to the Local view mode of the selection and examine each section.

[image]

Comment: I think that the simplest solution would be to write a script that would iterate the Bisect operator with different Z values. Meantime, I'll suggest an alternative solution that  it not optimized for your task, but is more flexible (you can arrange the planes in every way you want)